# how to replace null values in colum Salary with zero using groovy expression?

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf

I'm trying to calculate salary + bonus and show it in ADF `EmployeeRestrictedVO`
and I used this groovy expression: `salary + 600`.
But when `null` value comes error called `NullPointerException` appears.
So, I need groovy expression to replace the null values with zero.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be e.g.:

```
def bonus = salary ? salary + 600 : 600
```

Comment: Or `bonus = (salary ?: 0) + 600`